# I have a angular website and want to use ionic to create the mobile apps. Whats the easiest way?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a website that is created in Angular 4 (with Lumen as the Rest API) that has a responsive design.

The website works on desktop & mobile browser fine but now I want to create the mobile applications.

What is the easiest way to wrap ionic around my existing Angular website to create the mobile applications? The mobile applications will need camera, location, bar-scanning, etc. So I cant just webkit or webview the mobile applications, I would need the plugins from ionic / cordova.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to use any Ionic Components, so if you want to make visual changes to your app, or not.

If you have already created your application and it works/looks fine on mobile, there is no need to use Ionic. Ionic provides visual components to build hybrid apps that look like native apps, but if you don't need them, there is no need to use Ionic. Instead you can just use cordova, which allows you to take your existing webapp and simply add the native features like camera, location, etc. to it.

If you want to change your app and give it a native feel with Ionic, then it really depends on what kind of app you have and how big it is. It's not an easy task to take your existing app and put it "inside" Ionic. It might be easier to just create a new project and copy over the logic, but rebuild everything UI related with Ionic Components.

Comment: So if I would implement Cordova I would just use IF in app (iOS / Android) use cordova plugins ELSE use other methods like html5?

But if we rebuilt on top of ionic wouldn't our desktop web browser look, functionality and feel be hampered?